# Double graph with matplotlib: Attribute error

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have got a pandas dataframe like this:

```
nan 0     ingredient    contribution    count
0   0.0   cracker       0.088844873     11
1   2.0   water         0.044386494     125
2   3.0   oil           0.034567456     10
3   4.0   flour         0.030855063     186
...
```

I would like to create a double figure that looks something like this: 
[image: figure]

The code I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    #importing libraries
import numpy as np

plt.figure(1)   #creating empty figure

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)

fig_contr = df[['ingredient','contribution']]  #selecting columns
fig_count = df[['ingredient','count']]

plt.subplot(211)  #creating subplot
plt.plot(t, fig_contr)  #plotting subplot
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(t, fig_count)
```

But I get this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'find

How should I create the figure I would like to obtain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is use [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
plt.figure(1)   #creating empty figure

df.set_index('ingredient', inplace=True) #set index from column ingredient

fig_contr = df['contribution'] #selecting columns
fig_count = df['count']

plt.subplot(211)  #creating subplot
fig_contr.plot.bar()  #plotting subplot
plt.subplot(212)
fig_count.plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

You can also change orientation of labels of axis x:

```
plt.figure(1)   #creating empty figure
df.set_index('ingredient', inplace=True)

fig_contr = df['contribution'] #selecting columns
fig_count = df['count']

plt.subplot(211)  #creating subplot
fig_contr.plot.bar(rot=0)  #plotting subplot
plt.subplot(212)
fig_count.plot.bar(rot=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: graph1]

Comment: Thanks jezrael! Unfortunately I get the error message: TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot. Do you have an idea how to get rid of that?

Comment: What is `print df.dtypes` ?

Comment: The dtype is an object. Is it an integer/float in your case?

Comment: Huh I don't get it anymore.. Now I get another error: KeyError: 'ingredient'

Comment: Yes, you need convert to numeric - the easiest is use `astype` - `df['contribution'] = df['contribution'].astype(float)
df['count'] = df['count'].astype(int)`.

Comment: I I transfer to numeric with: df[['contribution','count']].astype(np.float). Then I still get this error: TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

Comment: Do you assign output? `df[['contribution','count']] = df[['contribution','count']].astype(float)`